# Access other scripts variables and classes of different directory

Tags: c#, unity

Im trying to learn how to access another scripts variable and classes of different direction, in Unity3D.
But for some reason it keeps giving me the error.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
public class Script_v2 : MonoBehaviour {

  public Vector3 size;

    public Player_Collission_Detection playerCollisionDetection;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        playerCollisionDetection = GetComponent<Player_Collission_Detection> ();

        size = playerCollisionDetection.size;
    }

}
```

Here is the what the directory looks like.

```
Assets
     _Scripts
          _Enemy
               Script_v2.cs
          _Player
               Player_Collision_Detection.cs
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import or "using" a custom class in Unity script?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20034/how-to-import-or-using-a-custom-class-in-unity-script)

Comment: I dont get what you mean

Answer (score 1):

The null reference exception basically says that there is no script of type Player_Collision_Detection attached on the game object. Location of the script file doesn't matter if it's placed somewhere inside the assets folder of Unity.

Just find script from the inspector and drag it on the game object you are trying run this script.

Comment: But cant i just find the script through code ?
And when you mean 'drag' what do you mean by that ?

Comment: Open up unity editor. There will be a tab named 'project'. Type in the name of the script; it will come up. Then, drag it on the game object from the hierarchy tab.

Comment: But wouldnt that give the content of the script to the gameObject ?
I just want to call variable from the script.

Comment: It creates a new instance from that script and adds it to the game object as a *component*.

Comment: But wouldnt it inherent the script that was added ?
I just want to reference one variable from that script and not the entire script itself.